# PHPMailer not working in localhost WAMP anymore

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Please help me out here I have tried possible solutions from former threads but it is not working.
My PHPMailer was working fine in localhost WAMP up until yesterday."SMTP() connection failed" There were no errors in my code, my "extension=php_openssl.dll" is uncommented in the php.ini file. I used port 587 and I even tried 465 but it still doesn't work anymore. My GMAIL allows lesser apps access. No typo errors but then all of a sudden i saw an error in my VScode "intelephense undefined  type PHPMailer error 1009" and it highlights lines $mail = new PHPMailer(true); and two more instances of PHPMailer. 3 red lines of that error message in total.

```
<?php
session_start();

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';



if ($_POST['admin_create']) {
    $name = $_POST['adm_name'];
    $email = $_POST['adm_email'];
    $pword = $_POST['adm_pass'];
    $tel = $_POST['adm_tel'];
    $house = $_POST['adm_house'];


    // instantiating and passing 'true' enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
    // enable debug output
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

    // send mail using SMTP 
    $mail->isSMTP();

    // set SMTP server to send through which mail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //SMTP Username or Usermail
    $mail->Username = 'davolufuwa@gmail.com';

    //SMTP Password 
    $mail->Password = '*********';

    //Enabling TLS encryption
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;

    //TCP Port number to connect to in PHPmailer is 465 and above
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Recipients of the code
    $mail->setFrom('davolufuwa@gmail.com', 'THE KAKEBOZZ');

    // Adding a recipient
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);

    //Setting Email format to HTML
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $verification_code = substr(number_format(time() * rand(), 0, '', 
    ''), 0, 6);

    $mail->Subject = 'Email Verification';
    $mail->Body = '<p> Your Verification Code is : <b style="font- 
    size:30px;">' . $verification_code . '</b>.<br> This code will 
    expire in 5 minutes.</p>';

    $mail->send();
    //echo 'Message has been sent';

    //encrypt the password
    $hashii = password_hash($pword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // connect to the database
    $con = mysqli_connect("Localhost", "root", "", "kakeboss");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (//i didn't put SQL query cos of question
    ) VALUES 
   ('$name','$email','$tel','$house','$hashii','$verification_code', 
    NULL)";

    $verify = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if ($verify) {
        $timestamp = $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"];
        $_SESSION['time'] = $timestamp;
        echo "PLEASE VERIFY YOUR EMAIL <a href='email_verification.php? 
    email=" . $email . "'>FROM HERE </a>";
    } else {
        echo "THAT WAS UNSUCCESSFUL";
    }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
    
    echo "message couldn't be sent.Mailer Error : {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: That error sounds more like VSCode not handling composer dependencies correctly than anything else, and it would not be responsible for any later SMTP issues. You have debug output enabled – what are you seeing exactly?

Comment: it saddens me but i just changed the port number to 465 again some minutes ago and the mailer is working again.

Comment: Ah, well that would be because implicit TLS (the `SMTPSecure` mode you're using) will not work on port 587, only port 465. This is [covered in the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#encryption-flavours).

Comment: makes me wonder why it was working in the first place. I sent over 20 emails through port 587

Comment: That will work by default because even it you don't tell it to, PHPMailer will spot that the server is advertising explicit encryption and enable it automatically. The same is not true of implicit TLS. My guess is that you changed it to use `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` without updating the port number as well.